# Way to title an oracle function or procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, sql-navigator

i have an issue. 
Description:
I have 2 schemas (a,b). in schema ‘a’, i implemented in a package ‘pac’  some functions and procedures( f1( par varchar2, par1 number),f2(par varchar2), p1(par number), p2 ). 
In the second schema I implement some functions in which I call some functions from schema a.pac : like this: 
In schema ‘b’:

```
    Var := a. pac.f1( text ,num);
```

By calling the function SQL Navigator shows me the function/procedure but not the Parameters. So I don’t know how  much parameters the function ‘f1’ get or how the parameter are ordered when i m in schema ‘b’. I have to navigate to schema ‘a’ to see the specification and is it annoying.
So my question:
Is there any trick in oracle to solve this issue.
A ways to use

```
    <! – ctext-- >
    comment on
```

in function procedure , package per example.
That would help me to give a titel to my packages, functions or procedures

Thx.
I use SQL Navigator 6.x.x

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment, but this might help you identify which parameters you are using and to get round having to specify them in a specific order.

If you have, In the `a.pac` package:

```
FUNCTION f1 (
  in_text  VARCHAR2(200),
  in_pi    NUMBER DEFAULT 3.14159,
  in_num   INT    DEFAULT 0
) RETURN NUMBER;
```

Then you can specify the parameters you are declaring:

```
var := a.pac.f1(
         in_text => 'abc',
         in_num  => 1
       );
```

or can even swap the ordering:

```
var := a.pac.f1(
         in_num  => 1,
         in_text => 'abc'
       );
```